# Log hwinfo output with etckeeper

Tags: etckeeper

I like etckeeper. It does store the etc/ directory in a git repository.

This way I have a nice history of what changed.

Of course we have backups, but this is convenient.

I would like to store additional data like the output of `hwinfo --all`.

The tool etckeeper seems to have a plugin "framework" via ".d" directories.

But I could not get it working.

How to store the output of hwinfo in a way, that etckeeper adds it to the git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating pre-commit hook for this:

You will create for example file /etc/etckeeper/pre-commit.d/40hwinfo with this code in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

hwinfo --all > /etc/hwinfo.txt
git add /etc/hwinfo.txt
```

then run:

```
$ chmod +x /etc/etckeeper/pre-commit.d/40hwinfo
```

and commit changes:

```
etckeeper commit
```

This will take little bit longer (because of time needed to complete the hwinfo command), but then you will see, you have your hwinfo output inside /etc/hwinfo.txt file and it will be tracked by git as well.

Comment: AFAIK the pre-commit hook will only run, if there are changes in the /etc directory. This means the @daily cron-job will do nothing, except there are by change changes in /etc.

Comment: regarding to what I see in the file /etc/etckeeper/daily, there is nothing that should prevent running hooks (at least on my Debian Stretch); but still you can do this without a hook, only with Cron, when you send output of `hwinfo --all` to file and then you'll call `git add /etc/hwinfo.txt` and also `etckeeper commit -m "...something..."` in this cron job.

Comment: You said "there is nothing that should prevent running hooks". I think the hook `40hwinfo` won't get executed if the etc directory is clean.

Comment: The probmel is in `/etc/etckeeper/daily` which gets executed by `/etc/cron.daily/etckeeper`. It only does commit if the repo is unclean.

Comment: Yes, your answer works. BUT: I need to activate this "AVOID_DAILY_AUTOCOMMITS=1" and create an own daily-cronjob with just does "etckeeper commit daily". The upstream cronjob does a lot of if-ing and else-ing and checking if clean or not ... Conditionless as goal seems to be new to the upstream author.